# no hover over text in ie/jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, hover

Please have a look: http://bestdesign.com.pl/klienci/tasta/strona/

Under the slides there are 4 divs with hover's that should show menus on slides.

The problem is in Internet Explorer 9 where there is hover on empty space but on text hover doesn't work.

It's made using jquery.

I tried with z-indexes but to no avail.
How can I fix it?

JS: https://gist.github.com/3379e19f4640b0d70300
CSS: https://gist.github.com/0ab86ed7656458377f98

Comment: show us your code if you need help

Comment: Post the code here or http://jsfiddle.net/ and send a link

Comment: it's too complex to just tear it out of page and post. I can send you the css/js but you must look at live page

Comment: Agree with those above. Please put only the relevant code in jsfiddle.net so we can have a play without needing to set it up ourselves.

Comment: Thanks Guys, you are right, with and you approach would certainly lead to solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this.  If you could provide the code would be much better.  However I noticed that you put the menu in block-menu-block-3 with a position absolute. and the text which is causing a problem in another block 'block-block-7'.

Have you tried to change it from

```
('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146').hover(function(){j('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146 a').show();
j('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146 ul').show();})
```

to

```
('.maintabs.tab-1').hover(function(){j('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146 a').show();
j('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146 ul').show();})
```

This way you will be targeting the div with text directly rather than the list with absolute positioning

Comment: yes but then if you mouse over to the menu which is another div it will disappear....

Comment: I'm trying to remember by heart hear but you could do $('#block-menu-block-3 li.menu-mlid-1146, .maintabs.tab-1').hover(function(){...code here})

Comment: THANKS! comma did it! I just added it and all is fine. I should accept you comment, but can only answer.